# Control is updated but no event is triggered

Tags: c#, datagridview

I've got a `DataGridView` which references objects on the application graph. For some reason, the cells are not updated when I add a curve on the graph via drag and drop. When I hover the cell of the data `DataGridView` some mysterious piece of code is executed. I put a breakpoint at each event triggered by the `DataGridView` but I was not able to find anything. If I debug step by step, the callstack says `External code`. Here are the events I follow:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
private void dataGridView1_RowsRemoved(object sender, DataGridViewRowsRemovedEventArgs e)
private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
private void dataGridView1_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e)
private void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
private void dataGridView1_RowContextMenuStripNeeded(object sender, DataGridViewRowContextMenuStripNeededEventArgs e)
private void dataGridView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
```

The DataSource is set, could this be the culprit ?

How can I investigate more ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [drag and drop cell from datagridview to another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21131157/drag-and-drop-cell-from-datagridview-to-another)

Comment: @t3chb0t no no, that's not what I want to do, I'll try to reformulate

Comment: What is the type of the object you set as the DataSource of the DataGridView?

Comment: @Junaith it's a              `BindingList`

Comment: What is the type of the BindingList element? Does it implement INotifyPropertyChanged properly?

Comment: @Junaith It's a custom type and it doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` (or I didn't search enough)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BindingList` element type has to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface for the `ListChanged` event to fire which in turn updates the `DataGridView`.

> **From MSDN:** ListChanged notifications for item value changes are only raised if the list item type implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in your custom type.